# COLLADA file import wrong geometry

Tags: collada

I have a DAE file that should create simple surface,
but when i import this file in any software i have wrong surface geometry, it have to be rectangle, but the shape is wrong.

```html
<geometry id="shape1-lib">
<mesh>
<source id="shape1-lib-positions" name="position">
<float_array id="shape1-lib-positions-array" count="12">
1738660495.4863 12684237096.632 0 
1738661083.5701 12684235726.5118 0 
1738664785.0153 12684237315.2499 0
1738664196.9315 12684238685.3702 0</float_array>
<technique_common>
<accessor source="#shape1-lib-positions-array" count="4" stride="3">
<param name="X" type="float" />
<param name="Y" type="float" />
<param name="Z" type="float" />
</accessor>
</technique_common>
</source>

<vertices id="shape1-lib-vertices">
<input semantic="POSITION" source="#shape1-lib-positions" />
</vertices>
<polylist material="CommonMaterial" count="1">
<input semantic="VERTEX" source="shape1-lib-vertices" offset="0" />
<input semantic="NORMAL" source="shape1-lib-normals" offset="1" />
<vcount>4</vcount>
<p>0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0</p>
</polylist>
</mesh>
</geometry>
```

Regards

Comment: How is it wrong? You cannot import the shape or you see a wrong shape? Your collada code cannot work because you have missing references to normals. If you add the normals array it should work. Your positions are also very far away from the origin. It might also be a problem for viewers.

Comment: I can see shape, it should be a rectangle, but it has wrong shape. 
I don't need normals here, because of vertexes.
Can you clarify item about positions please? What is origin and are there limits to coordinates? Because i've noticed that with small coordinates it works well.

Comment: if you don't need normals you should remove the references to normals source. It will cause problems with many viewers. The Collada itself doesn't define any limits to coordinates, but your viewer might. I cannot answer without knowing your viewer. That it works with small coordinates means your structure is correct, which I can also confirm. Your polylist is a correct defined rectangle.

Comment: Ok, i will remove normals source, thanks.
According viewers, all of used show wrong: BricsCAD, 3DSMax, PVSyst, Blender.

Comment: I think it is more a viewer problem. As you can see for Blender: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/limits.html They say +5000/-5000 are reliable. They don't guarentee anything outside these limits.

Comment: @Endery Thanks, for your help! Your answers were very helpful!